# Making form with vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make form with vanilla javascript. when `id="text"` value is nothing I meant space I want alert to pop, I'm makin' it with if statement but doesn't seem to work here's code

```
var input = document.getElementById('text');
function check(){
    if(input.value == " "){
        alert('hello');
    }
}
```

```
 Username: <input name="fname" type="text" onsubmit="check()" id="text" placeholder="Enter your username"> <br>
<button type="submit">asd</button>
```

Comment: and input fields do not have onsubmit events

Comment: `onsubmit` [should be](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onsubmit) a `<form>` attribute

Comment: @DaveNewton - _as long as it has been rendered_  -  how big a chance is there that a noob puts the script before the element ;)

Comment: @mplungjan Quite a good chance--but things should still be stated accurately.

Comment: Trim the input's value and check for empty; here you're checking for a *single* space, which I'm guessing does not meet your criteria (e.g., there could be two spaces).

Comment: You need to ask very specific questions: do you only care that it's *empty*, or do you want to disallow whitespace-only inputs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You need to get the field value every time the user clicks - if your initial code is not after the element, your code would fail, because `document.getElementById('text');` will be undefined
2. An input field does not have an onsubmit event
3. I recommend to have a value attribute too and trim it before testing

You likely mean this

```js
document.getElementById("form1").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  var input = document.getElementById('text');
  if (input.value.trim() === "") {
    alert('Please fill in user name');
    input.focus();
    e.preventDefault(); // stop form submission
  }
});
```

```html
<form action="yourserverprocess" id="form1">
  Username: <input name="fname" type="text" 
             id="text" placeholder="Enter your username" value="" /><br />
  <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

Without a form

```js
document.getElementById("subbut").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  var input = document.getElementById('text'), val = input.value.trim();
  if (val === "") {
    alert('Please fill in user name');
    input.focus();
  }
  else {
    console.log("You typed",val);
  }
});
```

```html
Username: <input name="fname" type="text" 
             id="text" placeholder="Enter your username" value="" /><br />
<button id="subbut" type="button">Send</button>
```

Comment: @cloned I'd disagree; the purpose of answers is to answer the question, not add additional information that obscures the underlying issue(s), especially for something as simple as this.

Comment: @Quentin Ah, yes you are correct ad 1 - assuming the code is after the element. Ad 3 - I certainly believe it is a good idea to have an initial known value - empty string if not set by the server

Comment: @mplungjan That *is* the known value; an un-filled text input has an empty string as its value. *shrug* It doesn't *hurt* to do it manually, but that's what it'll already be.

Comment: @DaveNewton [_Thus, when a form is reset, each control's current value is reset to its initial value. If a control does not have an initial value, the effect of a form reset on that control is undefined._](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html)

Comment: I still live in the past. Many things are now standard that were not. I no longer use `if (document.images)` but I do not trust form input values since so many now legacy browsers actually had undefined as default value. It does not hurt to make sure

Comment: @mplungjan This assumes a form reset (not the same as a re-render) which at this point does not seem to be the case here. That said, an empty form field will *always* send an empty string to the server (and as the JS `value`) these days. I also (tend to) favor being explicit, but for stuff like this, it Just Works (now).

Comment: so does `text.value` but I would never not access via getElementById or querySelector

Comment: @mplungjan *That* I wouldn't trust across browsers (IIRC it used to be that IE would automagicaly add IDed values as top-level vars, and Chrome appears to now, but that's not in any spec I know of. And I'm not going to look. Probably.

Comment: Hm it looks like that *is* in HTML 5, but is non-normative. But seems like a terrible, terrible idea. https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/window-object.html#named-access-on-the-window-object

Comment: IE would also return name="x" when you used getElementById("x")

Comment: That's even worse.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution of your problem. 
I've made some changes in your code. 
  1. you have to put onsubmit event in form tag. Because  doesn't support onsubmit event.
  2. Change the function name from check() to checkAlert(). May be check is a library keyword which causes your code to fail.

```js
var input = document.getElementById('text');

function checkAlert() {
 if(input.value == ""){
    alert('hello');
  }
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit = "checkAlert(this)">
   Username: <input name="fname" type="text" id="text" placeholder="Enter your username"> <br>
  <button type="submit">asd</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You should cancel the submit if the test fails. Also inline event handlers are no recommended. Please see my answer for a more complete solution

Comment: Yes, of course. You are right and your code is pretty good. But the owner of the post didn't say about any kind of form validation. That's why I gave the answer in short focusing his question. But in practical, your code should be used. @mplungjan Thank you